# Obtener los input de formulario en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, formularios

Hola amigos soy nuevo en laravel y estoy obstaculizado en lo siguiente: quiero tener control de cala texto que se introduce en los input de mi formulario pero no se como obtener el valor ingresado en los input.
Lo realice con Request y me funciona:

```
 class FormularioController extends Controller{

    public function mostrarDatos(Request $request){    

      $elemento1=$request->input('nombre');
      echo $elemento1;
   }
}
```

Pero yo quiero rescatar ese **input** con esta clase: **ValidarFormularioRequest** que extiende a la clase FormRequest(*en los tutoriales esta parte siempre lo dejaban para hacerlo a gusto del que miraba el tutorial*):

```
public function mostrarDatos(ValidarFormularioRequest $myrequest){

  //como obtener el input('name') ?  

}
```

Como podría realizarlo?

Comment: supongo que habrás probado `$myrequest->input('name');` o `$myrequest->input('nombre');` o como se llame el input. Si no te funciona así, agrega el código de `ValidarFormularioRequest`.

Comment: Si, gracias me sirvio, saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varias formas de hacerlo:

```
$request->input('nombre_campo');

$request->nombre_campo;

Input::get('nombre_campo');
```

Lo puedes ver en la documentación oficial:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#retrieving-input

Comment: Ohh estupendo gracias!

Answer (score 1):

ValidarFormularioRequest es para validar los datos del formulario no necesitas acceder a los inputs.

Te pongo un ejemplo de como solicitar que el campo nombre sea valido.
Este codigo seria el ValidarFormularioRequest.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class ValidarFormularioRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'nombre' => ['required']
    ];
}
/**
 * Get messages text.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'required' => 'Valor requerido',
    ];
}
}
```